# A uniformly convex normed vector space which is not reflexive

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, banach-spaces, examples-counterexamples

[Banach-Alaoglu theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Alaoglu_theorem) states that the closed unit ball of the dual space of a normed vector space is compact in the weak* topology, while [Milman–Pettis theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milman%E2%80%93Pettis_theorem) states that every uniformly convex Banach space is reflexive.

Let $(E, |\cdot|)$ be a Banach space and $B_E$ its closed unit ball. Let $J:E \to E^{**}$ be the canonical linear isometry. The proof of Milman–Pettis theorem in Brezis' *Functional Analysis* relies on the fact that $J(B_E)$ is closed in $E^{**}$ w.r.t. the norm topology. This fact follows from the fact that $E$ is complete.

> Could you provide an example of a uniformly convex normed vector space which is not reflexive?

Comment: An incomplete space?

Comment: @DavidMitra Ah, I'm being stupid. Any incomplete inner product space will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(H, \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle)$ be an incomplete inner product space and $|\cdot|$ its induced norm. By parallelogram law, $(H, |\cdot|)$ is uniformly convex. Because $H$ is incomplete, $H$ is not reflexive.

I have provided an explicit example of such space in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4688989/an-example-of-dense-subspace-of-ell-2) thread.