# An example of dense subspace of $\ell_2$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, examples-counterexamples, inner-products, orthonormal

Below is my explicit example of a uniformly convex normed vector space which is not reflexive. Could you confirm if my understanding is correct?

---

Let
$$
\ell_2 :=  \big \{ (v_n)_{n \ge 1} \subset \mathbb R^\mathbb N : \sum_n |v_n|^2 < \infty \big \}
$$
be equipped with the canonical inner product $\langle u, v \rangle := \sum_n u_n v_n$. Then $(\ell_2, \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle)$ is a separable Hilbert space. Let
$$
V := \big \{ (v_n)_{n \ge 1} \subset \mathbb R^\mathbb N : \sum_n n^2 |v_n|^2 < \infty \big \}.
$$

Then $V$ is a vector subspace of $\ell_2$. We have $(1, 1/2, 1/3, \ldots) \in \ell_2 \setminus V$, so $V \subsetneq \ell^2$. We define $e^m \in \ell^2$ by $e^m_n = 1$ if $n=m$ and $0$ otherwise. Then $(e^m)$ is an orthogonal basis of $\ell^2$. Clearly, $(e^m) \subset V$, so $V$ is dense in $\ell_2$. Hence $(V, \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle)$ is an incomplete inner product space.

We define a new inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_V$ on $V$ by  $\langle u, v \rangle_V := \sum_n n^2 u_n v_n$. Let's prove that $(V, \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_V)$ is a Hilbert space. We define a $\sigma$-finite measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb N$ by $\mu(n) := n^2$. Clearly, every $v \in \mathbb R^\mathbb N$ is $\mu$-measurable. For $v \in \mathbb R^\mathbb N$, we have
$$
\| v \|_{L^2(\mathbb N, \mu, \mathbb R)} = \sqrt{\sum_n n^2 |v_n|^2} = \sqrt{\langle v, v \rangle_V}.
$$

Then $L^2(\mathbb N, \mu, \mathbb R) = V$. It follows from $L^2(\mathbb N, \mu, \mathbb R)$ is complete that $(V, \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_V)$ is complete.

Comment: I don't quite understand the purpose of the last paragraph. $V$ is complete? (All you need is an incomplete subspace of a uniformly convex space. The set of elements in $\ell_2$ of finite support will do.)

Comment: @DavidMitra It's just my (related) understanding that would like to verify...

Comment: I also don't understand what are you trying to do obviously $V$ with two different inner products is not the same space.